Date filters in header filter out all records
I am testing out Tabulator and having a problem with header filters for date columns.
Please see this test page.
http://galcott.com/ortho/test.html
Click on any customer to see their orders. In one of the date columns, enter a date that you see in the data. It will say "No orders found". Then select any other customer and you will see "No orders found" for each one. Apparently it is maintaining that date filter and the only way to clear it is to refresh the page. What is going on here?
